# iAd errors in AdBannerView

Tags: ios, ios5, admob, iad

I have a test application with ads only in, for testing setup. It is setup to use admob mediation service, with iAd and admob ads being sent to the device.

I am seeing the following error occurs:

> [AppDeveloper]: ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0x9f82850 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}

Strange error as I have implemented the method for didFailToReceiveAdWithError, here is my full imp code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Create a view of the standard size at the top of the screen.
// Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

// Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
bannerView_.adUnitID = kAdMobPublisherID;

// Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
bannerView_.delegate = self;
bannerView_.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
// Make the request for a test ad. Put in an identifier for
// the simulator as well as any devices you want to receive test ads.
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"4D047EB9-A3A7-441E-989E-C5437F05DB04",
                       @"YOUR_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER",
                       nil];

}

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error;
{
    NSLog(@"Error - did Fail to Receive an Ad");
    bannerView_.hidden = YES;

}

- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)view;
{
    NSLog(@"Ad Received");
    bannerView_.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Regarding your flag, you should be able to answer your own questions. Is the system preventing you from doing so?

Comment: As such, I do not get a warning/error it just does nothing when I click on Answer Your Question button

Comment: Maybe you should report that as a bug or ask a question about it on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). You certainly should be able to answer your own questions, but maybe there's a bug with a certain version of your browser and the site currently.

Comment: Randomly the button is no longer dark grey and I can answer, strange thanks anyhow

Answer (score 0):

try to put `return self;` at the end of the methods so the delegate receives the error

Comment: You mean within the actual methods? i.e. after bannerView_.hidden= YES; return self; ?